# How to detect a new user in Slack?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm using Slack API and want to detect an event when user first joins a team but cannot find such type of event in docs.

What should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`team_join`](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join) might be the event you're looking for? Depending on whether you need to respond immediately (and the consequences of missing an event if your bot is offline), you might also consider just calling [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) periodically and comparing to the list of already-seen users.